# apt-get error - tries to install Dropbox

Tags: installation

everytime i put 'sudo apt-get update'  into Terminal it tries to install Dropbox.

How can I purge the Terminal of anything that may be in it. Something is holding up Software Center. Can't use Software center to install anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can try: `sudo apt-get purge dropbox`

Comment: Have tried that, this is what I get evertime I try to install a program from Software Center                                                                        .                                                                                       .                                                                        .Software can't be installed or removed because the authentication service is not available. (org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus-name', {'name':  ':1.61'}): org.debian.apt.install-or-remove-packages

Comment: Please update your question with the exact error message you are getting with `apt-get`